# Are there any context-free languages that are not regular but can be generated using a right-linear or left-linear grammar?

Tags: regular-languages, context-free

I understand that every regular language can be generated using either a right-linear or left-linear grammar, however, does that go the other direction? In other words, do there exist any context-free grammars that are not regular that are either right or left-linear?

Comment: Have you tried either writing a proof of this or looking for counterexamples? Commonly, the proof that every every regular language can be generated using either a right-linear or left-linear grammar takes an arbitrary DFA (or NFA) and explains how to create a right-linear or left-linear grammar having the same language. Can you do the same for the other direction?

Comment: I have looked for several counterexamples, but so far I've only been able to come up with grammars that are a mixture of right and left-linear.  This leads me to think that it isn't possible to create a right or left-linear grammar for a non-regular language, though I'm having a hard time coming up with an approach that proves it.

Comment: Why not begin with Google?
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar

Comment: You could give a procedure for turning an arbitrary right linear  grammar into an NFA, thus showing that the grammar has to correspond to a regular language (the same can be done for an arbitrary left linear grammar). It may be helpful to think of what the possible production rules in a right linear grammar can look like and how those would correspond to states/transitions in an NFA.